# How to implement 16-bit ADC (Analog to Digital Conversion) with Arduino - Atmel328 microcontroller?

Tags: arduino-uno

I am trying to use mcp3428 analog to digital converter for three channels voltmeter. Is there any sample code for mcp3428 to start with? I found one just for one channel, but I really want to use three out of four available channels. I have no idea how to pull data from different channels. I am working with arduino.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can properly read out channel 1:
Page 18 of the datasheet [here](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22226a.pdf) describes this. You need to change bits 5-6 in the configuration register

> 00 = Select Channel 1 (Default)
>   01 = Select Channel 2
>   10 = Select Channel 3 (MCP3428 only, treated as “00” by the MCP3426/MCP3427)
>   11 = Select Channel 4 (MCP3428 only, treated as “01” by the MCP3426/MCP3427)

This is done by using the I2C commands in the Arduino Wire Library [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Wire). The idea here is that you issue a write command to the configuration register and set bits 5 and 6 to the associated channel, then you do a normal read (again, assuming you have figured out how to properly read channel 1 data).

---